# Ms Project - Assign resource for fixed duration

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

Suppose we have two tasks T1 and T2 taking respectively 3 days and 10 days to complete, and two resources R1 and his best friend, R2. T1 starts on Nov 1rst and is supposed to finish on Nov 3rd, while T2 starts 5 days later on Nov 8th and finishes on Nov 18th. For the sake of simplicity, we assume the workers (R1 and R2) really love their job and work full time every day, including weekends.

This situation is pretty simple to model in MS Project (create the tasks and the ressources and assign R1 to T1 and R2 to T2 with 100% Max Unit)

Now suppose that R2 wins a contest which prize is a free trip to the country of his choice, including all the expenses. The only constraint is that the trip must take place between Nov 10th to 15th.

As the PM, I asked R1 if he wanted to replace R2 for the period of the trip, and be paid 50% more than usual. He accepted!

I am now trying to model that situation in MS Project but can't find a way to do it properly.

For the moment, I changed the Working time of R2 and added an exception that I named "Vacation" taking effect from Nov 10th to 15th. Doing this delayed the completion date of T2 by 5 days (makes sense). However, I want to assign R1 to the task T2 only from Nov 10th to 15th, but not for the full duration of the task.

I am looking for the following end result:

- R2 will work on T2 from Nov 8th to 9th
- R1 will work on T2 from Nov 10th to 15th (while R2 is on his trip)
- R2 will work on T2 from Nov 16th to 18th

That way, T2 will not be delayed.

Sorry if this kind of question has already been posted and answered. I searched but couldn't find what I was looking for. The closest post I could find was one where the OP wanted to assign multiple resources to the same task spread the work evenly during the whole duration of the task.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting manually in a usage view is a good way to go but doing so sort of ‘hides’ the new, custom work contour and some  people find that confusing. 
Another way might be to break that T2 into pieces, one for R1 and one for R2 with R2s bit just being the length of the split created by R1s cskebsar excretion. It’s a bit more cumbersome but it Kay’s tje work out in a way that is a bit more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Resource Usage page and adjust the hours for each resource manually.